Why is my website not responding when I expand my browser
Below i attached what my CSS looks like my webpage is a mixture of an audio player, an embedded twitter link and a few videos. when i open my webapage on my iphone the items appear centred but when i flip my phone horizontal I want the items to then respond into two columns rather than just a single column with an uneven amount of space on the right side of the page. I also want my webpage to respond when i open it on a ipad or macbook with the max amount of columns appearing being three and when the browser begins too shrink the webpage responds to a single column all while remaining centred please help me


* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
 
      }
  
      html, body {
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      }

      body {
      background-color: white;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;

      }

      .header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 35px 5%;
      font-family: 'Luxurious Script', cursive;
      font-size: 15px;
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 99;
      background-color: white; }

     .container-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: grid;
      }

      .grid {
      display: grid;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1200px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      }

    .grid-item {

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px;
    }

   .grid-item video,
   .grid-item .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    }

   .container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   padding: 50px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
   }

   .container:hover{
   box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   }

   h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
   }
 
   h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
   }

   .player-progress {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 40px 20px 35px;
    height: 6px;
    width: 95%;
    }

   .progress{
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.1s linear;
    }

   .music-duration{
   position: relative;
   top: -25px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   font-family: "Abel", sans-serif;
   font-size: small;
   }

   .music-duration span {
    margin: 0 10px;
    }

   .player-controls{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   top: -15px;
   left: 120px;
   width: 200px;
   }

   .bx {
   font-size: 30px;
   color: darkgrey;
   cursor: pointer;
   user-select: none;
   transition: all 0.3 ease;
   }

   .bx:hover{
   filter: brightness(40%)
   }

   audio-player {
   width: calc(100% - 40px) ;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   video{
   border-radius: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
  
   @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        .container-wrapper {
          padding: 0 20px;
        }
      }

    @media (max-width: 599px) {
    .grid-item {
       margin: 10px 0;
     }
    }
<body>

    <div class="container-wrapper">

    <div class="header">
    <h1>Cant Die Yet</h1>
    </div>
   

    <div class="grid">
    
    <div class="grid-item">

      <div class="container">

      <h2 id="music-title"></h2>
      <h3 id="artist-title"></h3>

      <div class="player-progress" id="player-progress">
        <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
        <div class="music-duration">
            <span id="current-time">0:00</span>
            <span id="duration">0:00</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="player-controls">

          <i class='bx bx-rewind' title="Previous" id="prev"></i>
          <i class='bx bx-play' title="Play" id="play"></i>
          <i class='bx bx-fast-forward' title="Next" id="next"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-item">

        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="400" height="420"> 
        <source src="video/C2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>   

        </div>

    <div class="grid-item">

        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="400" height="420"> 
        <source src="video/CASHA MAIN2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>   
    
        </div>
    
    
    <div class="grid-item">

        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="400" height="420"> 
        <source src="video/VANESSA1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>   
          
        </div>
            
    <div class="grid-item">

      <a class="twitter-timeline" 
      data-width="350" data-height="300" 
      href="https://twitter.com/cashbreed?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a> 
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
      charset="utf-8"></script>
       
    </div>  
    
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



Ive tried adjusting the margins and everything but it either just pushes my items off the screen when viewing on phone and nothing else seems to work or make a difference in responsiveness

We need to see the HTML to see how this CSS would be applied.

Looks like you are using the grid in wrong way.
I've added fully mobile responsive result.
I hope it will be help to you.
Thanks.


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px 5%;
    font-family: 'Luxurious Script', cursive;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: white;
}

.container-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
}

.grid-item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.grid-item video,
.grid-item .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.player-progress {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 40px 20px 35px;
    height: 6px;
    width: 95%;
}

.progress {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.1s linear;
}

.music-duration {
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: "Abel", sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
}

.music-duration span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.player-controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    top: -15px;
    width: 200px;
}

.bx {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.bx:hover {
    filter: brightness(40%);
}

audio-player {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

video {
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .grid-item {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }
}
<body>

    <div class="container-wrapper">

    <div class="header">
    <h1>Cant Die Yet</h1>
    </div>
   

    <div class="grid">
    
    <div class="grid-item">

      <div class="container">

      <h2 id="music-title"></h2>
      <h3 id="artist-title"></h3>

      <div class="player-progress" id="player-progress">
        <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
        <div class="music-duration">
            <span id="current-time">0:00</span>
            <span id="duration">0:00</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="player-controls">

          <i class='bx bx-rewind' title="Previous" id="prev"></i>
          <i class='bx bx-play' title="Play" id="play"></i>
          <i class='bx bx-fast-forward' title="Next" id="next"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-item">

        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="400" height="420"> 
        <source src="video/C2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>   

        </div>

    <div class="grid-item">

        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="400" height="420"> 
        <source src="video/CASHA MAIN2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>   
    
        </div>
    
    
    <div class="grid-item">

        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="400" height="420"> 
        <source src="video/VANESSA1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>   
          
        </div>
            
    <div class="grid-item">

      <a class="twitter-timeline" 
      data-width="350" data-height="300" 
      href="https://twitter.com/cashbreed?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a> 
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
      charset="utf-8"></script>
       
    </div>  
    
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>




the addition's to the media class definitely helped but I notice unless  I add margin 20px under my grid css when i open on my iphone safari browser the grid items are shifted slightly to the left side of the screen
